# Sharing a video from Photos, Yosemite

Tags: iphone, macos, photos, video

I filmed a video on my iPhone 5, the synced my phone with my computer, and the video was put into my photo library. I want to share this video on Facebook, but whenever I click on share >> Facebook, Photos says 'exporting files to be shared' and after about 25 minutes or so (the video is 2.6gb, its a 22 minute video) Photos finishes 'exporting' and then doesn't do anything. I don't get an alert telling me anything at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook has a limit of 1 Gig or 20 minutes Video.

Also RECOMMEND uploading video files in .MP4 format.

So you definitely need to cut back.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Guess it wasn't a 'Ask Different' question after all haha. What type of file does the phone have it has then? I would've thought .mp4

Comment: @MahmudAssamaray iPhone records in QuickTime `.mov` (H-264) format, 1080p@30fps.